# git - how to handle a branch "test"

Tags: git, merge

We have a repository that keeps the BSP & GUI Widget.
We then branch from master to write the main app, and unit test.
I created a branch from master to test the keypad widget : tst-keypad.

In this branch I merge updates from master, but sometimes I need to import back keypad bug fixes and new features.
Also, I add some code that belongs to the test (example : add inputs, and logs).

Until now I separate changes made in the keypad source code and those made in the test code in order to apply commits in master branch with cherry-picks (only keypad), as the merge would also apply the commit specific to the test.

```
           B1--B2--B3------   <-- branch test (HEAD)
          /        / <-- cherry-pick B3 because B1 and B2 are "test specific".
A1--A2--A3   <-- master
```

But very often I just make keypad improvments but I can't still use merge as it would also apply old test speficic commits.
Is there a way to "rebase" master as the next merge from test don't apply old commits ?

Answer (score 2):

While your workflow is far from standard and I recommend reconsidering it, that isn't really what you asked.  So:

> Is there a way to "rebase" master as the next merge from test don't apply old commits ?

There are ways to get this effect (not really by rebasing, though).  So for example, in your scenario above you have (after the cherry-pick):

```
A1 -- A2 -- A3 -- B3` <--(master)
              \
               B1 -- B2 -- B3 <--(test)
```

where `B3'` applies the same changes on `A3` as `B3` applied on `B2`.  So conceptually, at this time all changes up to and including `B3` are accounted for in master.  You just need to make git believe that.

So one option is to do a merge with strategy "ours".

```
git checkout master
git merge -s ours test
```

yielding

```
A1 -- A2 -- A3 -- B3` ------- M0 <--(master)
              \              /
               B1 -- B2 -- B3 <--(test)
```

where `M0` applies no changes to `B3'` but ensures that `B3` would be treated as the merge base if subsequent merges from `test` into `master`.

Using alternate strategies in merges can cause trouble if you ever do a rebase that includes the merge; however, such rebases generally aren't recommended anyway, and in this case the rebase would probably report conflicts during its attempt to reconcile the merge (because of `B3` and `B3'`).  Still, there are other options:

You could perform a "normal" merge from branch into master and then revert it.  This essentially tells git that you'll never want to incorporate that branch.  (But the initial merge will probably conflict.)

Or, *instead of cherry-picking `B3`* (so starting from

```
A1 -- A2 -- A3 <--(master)
              \
               B1 -- B2 -- B3 <--(test)
```

instead), you could

```
git checkout test
git checkout -b keypad_changes
git revert B1 B2
git checkout master
git merge keyboard_changes
git branch -d keyboard_changes
```

giving you

```
A1 -- A2 -- A3 --------------------------- M <--(master)
              \                           /
               \                !B2 -- !B1
                \              /
                 B1 -- B2 -- B3 <--(test)
```

This time `M` should be a "normal" merge - hopefully without conflict - that effectively applies *only* `B3` while still establishing `B3` as the merge base going forward.

Comment: That is interesting in the way you really answer to my howto question (you did it quickly tough!). In the second case that I found safer I realize that this procedure is quite creating a "virtual feature temporary branch" dedicated to the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you make feature branches and merge them in both branches. Then you don't have the problem that you have some commit that you don't want in your production system.

Atlassian has a great tutorial for workflows

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows

There is a part for feature branching and other very good parts how to handle branching.

Comment: So you sugget I create a keypad-branch, and a keypad-tst branch. Then all tst commit specific stay in its branch. As an old cvs user I find branching that way may lead to ininfite branching and need someone dedicated to maintenance :).

Comment: It is an eclipse project that compiles one binary,so only one main() main remains active in source. I'm still wondering if I shall put in master the test source code (and use makefile settings to create profiles compilation). Thanks for the link.